# Outputted something else when slicing strings

Tags: python, string

I am relatively new to python.
I was trying to create a program which would read parts of a little janky command system but it would output the wrong thing. I don't know what's wrong. Is there a better solution?

I typed in "-mp 1A -10 -15 18 20" and it couldn't read the 4 numbers.

Here is my code:

```
n = -50
while run == True:
    
    func = input("")

    if "-mp" in func:
        que = func[4:7]
        for i in range(200):
            
            n = n+1
            m = str(n)
            
            if m in func[7:10]:
                
                x1 = n
                print(x1)
                n = -100
                break
        
        for i in range(200):

            n = n+1
            m = str(n)
            
            if m in func[11:14]:
                
                y1 = n
                print(y1)
                n = -100
                break
        
        for i in range(200):

            n = n+1
            m = str(n)
            
            if m in func[15:19]:
                
                x2 = n
                print(x2)
                n = -100
                break
        
        for i in range(200):

            n = n+1
            m = str(n)
            
            if m in func[19:22]:
                
                y2 = n
                print(y2)
                n = -100
                break
```

Comment: What exactly does "it couldn't read" mean? What did it do instead? What was it supposed to do?

Comment: Like it didn't get the exact values I typed. It said 1, -1 0 or something.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using `func.split(" ")`?

Comment: `func[19:22]` outputs `0` and I suspect you anticipate it to be `20`. At any rate, trying to read these flags by character position is ugly business. Instead split the func string by a space and then reference the position of the term by its index: `func.split(" ")[5]`

Comment: Point is that it wouldn't print the exact same values I typed in (i.e -10, -15, 18 and 20).

Comment: Right. It's not printing what you typed in because you are referencing the wrong position in your strings `func[18:21]` for that last loop is what you are after. To troubleshoot on your own add `print(func[15:19])` and `print(func[19:22])` in your code to see how are you mishandling this slice. It would be very illuminating for you, I suspect.

Comment: To get your parameters you really want to split the input string or better yet use argparse or even sys.args rather than using slices

Comment: Check out [ask] for tips like how to write a good title.

Comment: Guys don't worry now I found the solution

Comment: By the way guys, I have solved my problem, so it's OK and I don't want any more responses flooding my inbox.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to print exclusively the numbers included in the `-mp` command. You could easily achieve that using a `for` loop in the while loop. Furthermore, you will want to use the `re` library to find all the inputs, including letters such as the `A` in `1A`. Here is a snippet that does exactly that, no matter in what order the inputs are passed into the `-mp` command:

```py
import re
while run == True:
    func = input("Enter something: ")
    if "-mp" in func:
        que = func.split(" ")
        for i in que:
            if not re.search(r'[a-zA-Z. ]', i) and i != '-mp':
                print(i)
```

After the `while` loop is started and the `-mp` command is initiated, you will first want to split the input text at all spaces (" "), which results in a list that you can iterate through: `que = ['-mp', '1A', '-10', '-15', '18', '20']`. When you iterate through the list, you will want to check for two things:

1. Does the item ("`i`") include a letter? This is achieved by using `re.search`. Simply put, this goes through your item and returns `True` if a letter is found. This is why we use `if not ...` because we only want to look at items that do *not* include a letter (it is imperative that we look for letters because looking for only numbers would result in all inputs being printed, as all inputs include at least one number!).
2. Does the item include the command indicator `-mp`? If it doesn't, we can continue, as we can be sure we are not looking at the indicator. For that, we use the `!=` operator, which is basically the opposite of `==`, which we use to make comparisons.

Now, we can be absolutely sure that only numbers are passed to the `print` statement, which will ultimately present the numbers passed into the command.

Answer (score -1):

```py
n = -50
run = True

while run:
    func = input("Enter a string: ")

    if "-mp" in func:
        indices = [7, 11, 15, 19]
        values = []

        for index in indices:
            substr = func[index:index + 3]
            for _ in range(200):
                n += 1
                m = str(n)
                
                if m in substr:
                    values.append(n)
                    print(n)
                    n = -100
                    break

        if len(values) == len(indices):
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = values
            print(f"x1: {x1}, y1: {y1}, x2: {x2}, y2: {y2}")
```

i am sorry if its wrong i rty and make some changes

Comment: For some reason it didn't work with the code but worked by itself.